# Why are the two ways different results?(Django Rest Framework 3.9)

Tags: python, django

Same code different results. So, why?

```py
# prj001 is the app name

# MyUser 
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True,)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    area = models.CharField(max_length=100,
                            null=True)
    ...

users = MyUser.objects.values('area').distinct()  # user

# Generalinfo 
class GeneralInfo(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey('myuser.MyUser',
                              null=True,
                              related_name='mygi',
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    hospital = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...

info_one = Info.objects.values('hospital').distinct()    # first

print(info_one.query)

info_two = Info.objects.order_by('hospital').values('hospital').distinct()  # second

print(info_two.query)
```

1. user:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT `myuser_myuser`.`area` FROM `myuser_myuser`
```

2. first:

```sql
# recdate is a DateField
# recdate = models.DateField(default=date.today)
SELECT DISTINCT `prj001_generalinfo`.`hospital`, `prj001_generalinfo`.`recdate`, `prj001_generalinfo`.`id` FROM `prj001_generalinfo` ORDER BY `prj001_generalinfo`.`recdate` DESC, `prj001_generalinfo`.`id` DESC
```

3. second:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT `prj001_generalinfo`.`hospital` FROM `prj001_generalinfo` ORDER BY `prj001_generalinfo`.`hospital` ASC
```

user and first : Obviously, they are same. But The corresponding query is different.

I want to the user result is the same to the first one.
And, The third form meets my requirements.

Comment: There is not enough information here to understand what you are asking. We can't really answer without knowing what these models contain, and what your expected output is, and why you think it is wrong.

Comment: what actual problem are you facing. Post your model code

Comment: please describe both the model you have, what fields are present and how they are related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the first `distinct()` query doesn't give you distinct values but the second (with a specific `order_by` clause) does, then you have a default `ordering` defined in your `Info` model.

You can use an empty `order_by()` (or a different `order_by` as in your example) to disable the default ordering.

The reason is that columns used for ordering are included in the SQL query and therefore in the distinct comparison even though they are not returned to the user (resulting in duplicate rows). The [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) explain this extensively.